# Manipulate json and send it into web request using Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, httprequest

I'm trying to manipulate a json object and send it as content into the body of a put / post web request. The source of my json is a file on my disk.

This is my Powershell script:

```
$urlBase = 'https://mysite.myapp.com/service/api/Item/'

$myJson = (Get-Content 'file.json' | ConvertFrom-JSON)   

# Then I manipulate my object
$id = $myJson.id
$myJson.version = '1.2.3.4'

# Request
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ($urlBase + $id) -Method Put -Body $myJson -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $hdrs
```

When I execute my script y get this error message:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:18 char:17
+ ... $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ($urlBase + $id) -Method Put -Body ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

If I change my $myJson asignment for this the request works fine...

```
$myJson = Get-Content 'file.json'
```

... , but then I can't manipulate my json before send it.

**Edited:**
If I try to convert back using ConvertTo-Json I get the same error:

```
$convertedBack = $myJson | ConvertTo-Json

# Request
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ($urlBase + $id) -Method Put -Body $convertedBack -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $hdrs
```

Comment: Can you not convert it back after you have manipulated what you want to ( ConvertTo-Json )

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. I've edited my post with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments: you need to convert your object back to JSON using the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet.

I see that you've tried that now and had the same problem. So I ask you this: is the value of `$convertedBack` exactly what you expected? Dump it to file and check!

The reason I am suspicious of this detail is that `ConvertTo-Json` has a little gotcha in it. Specifically the `-Depth` parameter which can cause some data loss.

## `-Depth`

> Specifies how many levels of contained objects are included in the JSON representation. The default value is 2.

## Example Without `-Depth`

```
$basicJsonObject = @"
{
    "name": "George",
    "properties": {
        "mood": "jovial",
        "coffee": {
            "hasCoffee": true,
            "mugContents": {
                "milk": false,
                "doubleShot": true
            }
        }
    }
}
"@

$psObject = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $basicJsonObject

Write-Host "Freshly Imported"
Write-Host "DoubleShot = $($psObject.properties.coffee.mugContents.doubleShot)"

$convertedBack = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $psObject

$reConverted = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $convertedBack

Write-Host "Re-Converted"
Write-Host "DoubleShot = $($reConverted.properties.coffee.mugContents.doubleShot)"
```

### Results

```
Freshly Imported
DoubleShot = True
Re-Converted
DoubleShot =
```

## Example **With** `-Depth`

Change one line of code:

```
$convertedBack = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $psObject -Depth 5
```

### Results

```
Freshly Imported
DoubleShot = True
Re-Converted
DoubleShot = True
```

Note how the new results include the value from the `$reConverted` variable. This is because the data is not lost further upstream!